# equivalence in simplicial category

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, enriched-category-theory, simplicial-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C},W)$ be a category with weak equivalences. One can build from $(\mathcal{C},W)$ its hammock localization $L^{H}(\mathcal{C},W)$ which is a simplicial category $\textit{ie}$ a category enriched in simplicial sets. I wonder if there is a notion of equivalence in  $L^{H}(\mathcal{C},W)$ between two objects ?

I can guess a possible answer:

An equivalence in $L^{H}(\mathcal{C},W)$ between X and Y is just an equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$, $\textit{ie}$ a map in $W$, between X and Y, namely a hammock of length 1 in $L^{H}\mathcal{C}(X,Y)_{0}$.

Or more generally any hammock of length n for any $n\ge 0$ in $L^{H}\mathcal{C}(X,Y)_{0}$ such that any map in the row is an element in $W$ (not only the maps that go to the left).

Or more generally any hammock of length n for any $n\ge 0$ which is a k-simplex, $\textit{ie}$ an element of $L^{H}\mathcal{C}(X,Y)_{k}$, such that not only the vertical maps are in $W$ but also all the horizontal maps.

Comment: An equivalence in a simplicial category $S$ is a map (i.e.~a vertex in some morphism simplicial set) which becomes an isomorphism in $\pi_0S$.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: I don't understand what you mean by a "vertex in some morphism simplicial set". Moreover, since $\pi_0S$ is a discrete groupoid I guess you mean "becomes an identity in $\pi_0S$"?

Comment: In simplicial categories, morphism objects are simplicial sets, so they do have vertices. For a simplicial category, $\pi_0S$ is not a discrete groupoid, it's a category.

Comment: thanks Fernando, where I can find the definition of $\pi_0S$ for $S$ a simplicial category ? In the nlab I only found the def of $\pi_0X$ for $X$ a Kan complex.

Comment: Is your proposal the same as saying: two objects $X,Y\in L^H\mathcal{C}$ are equivalent if there exists an element of $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)_0$ and an element of $L^H\mathcal{C}(Y,X)_0$ such that the composition of these 0-simplices (in both directions) are related to the identities by a 1-simplex ?

Comment: If you put your second definition i.e. "more generally any hammock of length $n$ for any $n\geq 0$ in $L^{H}\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ such that any map in the row is an element in W" is the "right" definition since it is equivalent to the proposition "$X$ and $Y$ are equivalent if and only if there exists an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ in the associated homotopy category $\pi_{0}L^{H}\mathcal{C}= \mathcal{C}[W^{-1}]$.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It's about an elementary fact of simplicial categories and has been answered in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Let's think of any simplicial category, $\mathbf{C}$. It's homotopy category is written as $\mathrm{h}\mathbf{C}$, $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathbf{C})$, and even as $\pi_0(\mathbf{C})$ (the last is Fernando's notation). By definition, a map $X\to Y$ in $\mathbf{C}$ that is an *isomorphism in $\pi_0\mathbf{C}$* is an equivalence. So in your case, $\mathbf{C}$ is the hammock localization $\mathrm{L}^H(\mathcal{C,W})$. The homotopy category $\pi_0\mathrm{L}^H(\mathcal{C,W})$ is $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$, the localization with respect to the weak equivalences (obtained by inverting all the morphisms in $\mathcal{W}$); thus, by the above discussion, *a map $X\to Y$ in $\mathrm{L}^H(\mathcal{C,W})$ is an equivalence if and only if it is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$*. This is, as Fedotov says, equivalent to your second definition.